# Can not find Symbolic link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have created a new site under /var/www on Ubuntu. I decided to use some of the structure from a site already in the /var/www directory.  For some reason when I hit the new site the console shows an error and it is referencing a js file from the site I copied the structure.

During the process of trying to figure out the problem I have deleted the js directory in the new site and still the error comes up and console shows a path to the js file to be the path to the directory I deleted.  The file appears to be a copy of the file from another site.

Do I have a symbolic link I do not know about.  I have tried the 'find -type l' in the var/www directory and it did not find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it makes sense to find out what exactly is referrencing that file, probably by

```
find /var/www | xargs grep 'yourjsfile.js' -sl
```

Comment: Using that command does not show any thing unusual.  The name of my file is common.js and I use that in two other sites in the www directory. Each site has it's own common.js file in its own js directory. Using the command you suggested shows references I would expect.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined and the file referenced is common.js. I click on the file and it shows code from a file in another directory but hovering over the file shows a path to a deleted directory in the site I am going too. I have double checked the available site and settings and disabled and enabled. restarted appache and reviewed the htaccess file to make sure it does not reference the other site. What is perplexing is if the problem was a direction issue by the htaccess or the document root in sites available wouldn't all the files be wrong.

Comment: Problem solved. I forgot to put the virtual host in the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file